# “Buried him by Christian religion”

Tags: prepositions

> Mr Jackson passed away a couple of weeks ago. As he was Christian his family buried him by Christian religion.

Is it correct to use *by* in this sentence?

Comment: No, _according to_ or _according to local practices of_ would be the idiomatic choice.

Comment: 'Buried him in a Christian manner' would be more idiomatic. Or, 'according to Christian teaching/custom/doctrine'. 'By' does not equate to 'because of' or 'through'. 'By' is an ablative expression, not a dative one.

Answer (score 3):

His family gave him a Christian burial. That's  the standard idiom.

You can check it here: [Christian Burial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christian_burial)

Typically, we say: give a person a [name of religion or the denomination of a religion] burial

Answer (score 0):

The OED attests to an old sense of *religion* as the performance of religious rites or observances, for example in Milton,

> Oft to the Image of a Brute, adornd / With gay Religions full of Pomp and Gold

or Leoni's translation of Alberti,

> The Ancients used to found the Walls of their Cities with the greatest religion, dedicating them to some God who was to be their guardian.

It marks this sense as *rare*, however, as the overwhelmingly most popular meaning of *religion* today is of a particular system of faith in the divine and its corresponding systems of cosmology, morality, ritual, and so forth, and related metaphorical usages, or such systems in general.

It would be far more idiomatic to say his family buried him *according to Christian practice*, or *in the Christian manner*, or that they *gave him a Christian burial*. If you must use *by*, I would suggest *by the Christian tradition*.